# What does Yarmulka mean?

Tags: minhag, words, etymology, yiddish, kippa-yarmulka

What does the word Yarmulka mean?

Answer (score 12):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yarmulke):

> Etymology: Yiddish *yarmlke*, from Polish *jarmułka* &  Ukrainian *yarmulka* skullcap, of Turkic origin; akin to Turkish *yağmurluk* rainwear

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't mean anything. It stands for Yaray Malka. (Fear of G-d)

Comment: "Malkah" means "King" in Aramaic.

Comment: Why the extra 'h'?

Comment: that is why shlomo wrote malka.  were his name shlomoh, he probably would have written yaray malkah!